# Pre loader on window load

Tags: javascript

I have found this loader but not sure if its actually loading content or just running numbers. I am new to JavaScript, I want it to load the page but every time I run it counts all the way I don't see it slow down with heaver images so I am not sure if it is actually loading the page.

```js
'use strict';

loader();

function loader(_success) {
    var obj = document.querySelector('.preloader'),
        inner = document.querySelector('.preloader-inner'),
        page = document.querySelector('body');
    obj.classList.add('show');
    page.classList.remove('show');
    var w = 0,
        t = setInterval(function () {
        w = w + 1;
        inner.textContent = w + '';
        if (w === 99) {
            obj.classList.remove('show');
            page.classList.add('show');
            clearInterval(t);
            w = 0;
            if (_success) {
                return _success();
            }
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

```css
.preloader {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.preloader-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
    <div class="preloader-inner"></div>    
  </div>
```

Comment: Yep, it's literally just running numbers. I'm guessing you have to give it the content you want it to pre-load. This isn't the best approach for pre-loading either. I suggest you try one of the many libraries and when that doesn't work coming back with a question that explains exactly what you want to pre-load and what you tried

Comment: @FredStark yea all i want is a number preloader I have looked and researched i found one on codepen which was listed above I just want a windows on load with precentage

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. You want it to display loading progress, not to pre-load assets. The hardest part is knowing how big the page is before the page is loaded. So I strongly recommend a library like http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ instead of rolling your own

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question of a sort you need to ask. You need to understand the language bit more. My suggestion is if you are using a method which you didn't write find out what it does. e.g: **setInterval()**

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Your loader just increments numbers from 0 to 99 in a 20-millisecond interval. Just a loop.

There are enough libraries available to implement such functionality and with a lot of examples. Do your research.